# selecting a div with a dynamic class name

Tags: html, css

While working on a site I came to a situation where I needed to select div classes with a dynamic id number. For instance every new div class would carry it's "id" from my database in its class name like so:

```
<div class="reply_to_08"></div>
```

So I could do this

```
.reply_to_08 {}
```

But I didn't want to write a new css selector for every div. I wanted to select all of them that had the ".reply_to_" in it while ignoring the "08" that being the dynamic number.

So I found a solution on a blog post on a website which was:

```
div[class^=reply_to_]
```

Well it worked, but there was no explanation as to why that would work or how it would work. And I can't seem to understand it.

Can someone explain as to why that works? And is this method recommended or is there another way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is the `^=` pattern of the **[Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** (`[class^=reply_to_]`).

In your case, the `^=` will let you select every element whose `class` attribute value begins with `"reply_to_"`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors for documentation on what you're doing. Also, this will not work on IE6 (if you have the misfortune of supporting it still)

Comment: IE6 isn't an issue here. I appreciate the response.

Comment: `^` sign is *not* an *attribute selector*, but rather a small piece of one. The *attribute selector* in this case is `[class^=reply_to_]`. The *pattern* is `^=`. And `^` is the first character of the *pattern*. It can't be narrowed down more than that. May I suggest wording such as: "The key is the `^=` pattern of the **Attribute Selector** `[class^=reply_to_]`." instead? Also, the wording of the second sentence is a bit off. Perhaps you mean "In your case..." (`you` > `your`) and "...let you select every element whose..." (`Selects` > `select`, remove `a `)?

Comment: @SKS, in regards to your change, the new wording `(in [class^=reply_to_])` makes it sound as if the *attribute selector* is in `[class^=reply_to_]`, but the *attribute selector* **is** `[class^=reply_to_]`. Easy fix is to simply remove `in ` from within the parentheses. Either way, nice improvement, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The ^= stands for starts with. In your case that means you select every div that has a class that starts with "reply_to_".

That is the whole trick.

Answer (score 0):

`E[foo^="bar"]` - an `E` element whose `foo` attribute value begins exactly with the string `bar`.

— [W3C Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) specification.

**Note:** *IE 7+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 3.2+, Opera 9.5+ (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)*

Comment: You ref to the browser support is about the :nth-child and :last-child selectors, which indeed is IE 9+. The E[foo^="bar"] selector however is supposed to be supported by IE7 and above.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson, yes, you're right. I'll update right now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is section 6.3.2 of the CSS3 spec:

6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors
Three additional attribute selectors are provided for matching substrings in the value of an attribute:

[att^=val] 
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything. 
[att$=val] 
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything. 
[att*=val] 
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Answer (score 0):

That is a CSS selector that is new for CSS3. Here's a post about the [CSS3 selectors](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/), with a short section that about the one you are referring to.

What it says is basically "starts with", so in your case the selector `div[class^=reply_to_]` says give me all div-elements that has a class whose class-name starts with "reply_to".

Notice that the selector is CSS3 specific, so the support for the selector will be limited in older browsers.

**Update** Apparently the "starts with" selector is supported by IE7 and above, so the support seems pretty decent, if you're not stuck with IE6 support (in that case, sorry about that). Here's a [full list](http://www.css3.info/modules/selector-compat/) of the browser support for selectors.